# What are the key uses of the Mothership and Mothership Core's "Time Warp"?

Tags: starcraft-2

The mothership's vortex ability was replaced with "Time Warp", this is also an ability added to the new mothership core.

What uses does time warp have? The ability isn't useful for kiting due to the limited range, duration and cost, so for a vessel that only one can be built a time - why should I use my energy on this ability?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Time Warp**
Time warp is often used by the pros to prevent kiting, delay a two pronged attack or just literally delay a whole attack. Remember that TimeWarp only affects movement speed, it does not affect attack speed. The basic of protoss early and mid game engagements stays the same: engage in choke points to abuse your ffs and not be overwhelmed as easily.

Time warp AoE is large enough to affect most of a 3 ff wide ramp. It can help make the units come up slower (stimmed marines, speed roaches) and makes ffs easier on units in the Time Warp. It also make kiting harder for range units like the marines and marauder. Used correctly, it will allow your zealots to get the 3-4 additional attacks that can make the difference between losing a battle or not losing a battle.

If a two pronged attack is about to hit your middle game army, dropping the Time warp on one of the push will give you more time to attack the opponents army the way you want. It can also force the opponent to go where you want him to go since engaging anytime in a time warp is a bad idea because of the movement slow.

If you see a big army coming your way, dropping the TimeWarp will delay this army since, like I said before, engaging in a timewarp in the middle game where the Protoss has either colossus or templars is a bad idea. It might also allow you to drop money storms during a battle since dodging a storm in time warp is close to impossible.

These are the things I've seen WhiteRa, Grubby and Huk do with the TimeWarp.

Also just remembered, TimeWarp on the worker line slows mineral income, funny little use for it if your momma core ends up behind an enemy line.

**Photon Overcharge**
Allows your nexus to become a cannon for a limited amount of time. It will make 1 gateway fe easier to pull off. The photon overcharge gives your nexus the attack of a cannon and the range of a siege tank (or a little bit more than a siege tank). It allows for quick defense and makes the use of a cannon less of a must while early expanding.

Also, a troll tactic of doing a planetary nexus in your opponents main can work if done right and your opponent is in the lower leagues.

**Mass recall**
It is best used for hit and run type of attacks with your army. It allows you to teleport after a small delay to any nexus on the map. Perfect for hitting the zerg third and then defending your own third. Or moving fast across the map in the late game when you have 5-6 bases.

EDIT: Just noticed that you might want all of the uses of the momma core abilities, so I added more.

Answer (score -3):

The new core ability is the [MassRecall](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Mass_Recall)

From the wiki:

> Mass Recall is a spell cast by the Protoss Mothership. Very similar to the ability of the Arbiter from StarCraft 1, Mass Recall teleports a group of friendly Protoss units within a 6.5 radius of a targeted area directly to the Mothership's position. Such a teleportation can occur from across the map, allowing the Protoss player to instantly change their army's position. Units that teleport to the Mothership also gain the advantage of its Cloaking Field.

Another excerpt from the wiki explains perfectly its utility:

> The Mass Recall spell can evacuate trapped offensive units to safety, or allow an otherwise immobile army to defend or attack more than one key location on the map.

The [Time Warp](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Mothership_%28Heart_of_the_Swarm%29#Spells) is actually limited for balancing purposes and, community wise, the Mothership is used mostly as a cheesy unit or for its passive Cloaking ability.

You should check [this interview](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=383169) to Dustin Bowder, where he points out this:

> Will redesign Mothership so it won’t be a serious unit used in professional esports play

Comment: I wasn't really interested in Mass Recall, and saying that it is a "a cheesy unit" and it is "limited" doesn't really answer the question.